# Show $f$ is continuous everywhere but nowhere differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_ncos(b_nx)$$ with $a_n = 10^{-n}$ and $b_n = 10^{n^2} $ is continuos but nowhere differentiable.That is uniformly continuos is obvious since $$\sum a_n < \infty$$

To study differentiable I have been triyng some calculations without success. For example, try to undestand $f(x+h)-f(x)|$, I put $h = \frac{2\pi}{10^{n_0^2}}$ to cancel terms in the sum, arriving to $$|\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}a_n(cos((x+h)b_n) - cos(xb_n))|$$ Now what I have tried is using the fact that $|a+b|>||a|-|b||$ to, for example, take the last term of the sum, and see if the sums of the others terms can be small enough to not cancel it. Some ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using a trig formula for $\cos A - \cos B$?

Comment: No! What I've tried is separate $cos(x+h)$ as $cos(x)cos(h)-sen(x)sen(h)$. I forget the formula that you suggest, I will try it

Comment: Well, I couldn't conclude something more :p

Comment: **HINT**: What do you know about $\dfrac{\sin(b_nh/2)}h$ for $h$ small? I haven't thought about the rest of the estimate.

Comment: Thats a great point but I think is not just that, you can make sure that the first terms in the finite sum will have a $b_n$. The problem is that the term $cos(2xb_n+hb_n)$ could be extremely small and cancel the $b_n$ outside. I think this is more visible looking the same count but in cosines: $\frac{cos((x+h)b_n)-cos(xb_n)}{h}$ in the first terms in the sum will be aproximately $sen(b_nx)b_n$ but how can one tell if this small or big

Comment: Sorry, which rule is that?

Comment: derivative of 10^-n cos (10^n x) = - sin (10^n x)

Comment: Take the derivative as a power series. Note it is not convergent.

Comment: Thus the derivative is sum -sin(10^n x) but this doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

> **Large comment**
>
> Fix some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider the difference:
> $$f(x+h)-f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(b_n(x+h))-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(b_nx)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(\cos(b_n(x+h))-\cos(b_nx)),$$
> since both series are absolutely convergent. We also have:
> $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{\cos(b_n(x+h))-\cos(b_nx)}{h}.$$
> Now, since $\cos(b_nx)$ is didderentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, from M.V.T. there exists some $\xi_n=\xi_n(h)$ between $x$ and $x+h$ such that:
> $$-b_n\sin(b_n\xi_n)=\frac{\cos(b_n(x+h))-\cos(b_nx)}{h}.$$
> So, we have:
> $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n\sin(b_n\xi_n)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty10^{n^2-n}\sin(10^{n^2}\xi_n).$$
> Note that now you can take $\xi_n$ to be arbitrarily close to $x$, since $\xi_n$ is dependent on $h\neq0$ and then you can verify that the last series does not converge.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nice idea but I do not see how you can control the $sin(b_n\zeta_n) $ because if you take for example $x$ to be a zero of the sine then maybe you have $sen (10^{n^2}\zeta_n)$ arbitratily small, even smaller than $a_nb_n $. How do you control that?

Comment: I do no know if I explain my idea correctly, the problem I see is that maybe the argument of the sine are arbitrarily close to zeros of the sine when you increment $n$, and then maybe is sufficient small to cancel the effect of $a_nb_n$

Comment: Yeap, I see your point. The trouble occurs at $x_{k}=\dfrac{k\pi}{b_n}$. I will edit my answer as soon as possible. I think that using Cauchy's MVT and some trigonometry solves this case as well but I'll have to write it down first. As for $x\neq x_k$, the above method works fine. Excuse me for my mistake! :)

Comment: What I am convinced is that you can made the $sin (\zeta_nb_n)$ close to $sin (x b_n) $ but this maybe close to zero

Comment: Ok! There is no problem of course :)

Comment: I think the only point we have to discuss is $x=0$, since, if $x\neq0$ and $x$ is some root of any term of the final series, then there must exist some $n,k$ such that $x=\frac{k\pi}{b_n}$. However, this might be a root of finitely many terms since, for any $m>n$ such that $b_m>|k|$ we have that $-\pi<x<\pi$ and, hence, $x$ is not a root of the $m-$th term. Thus, we can just ignore the first terms and work with the series' tail.

Comment: But if $\zeta_nb_n $ tends to a root we are in problem! Because maybe $a_nb_nsen (b_n\zeta_n) $ tends to 0

Comment: Since $b_n=10^{n^2}$, $xb_n$ diverges but for $x=0$.

Comment: mmm i think i get it, if$ xb_n $ is not a zero then $b_n\zeta_n $ wont be close to a zero...

Comment: I've made another edit regarding $x=0$.

Comment: Well, thanks for your efforts. I am convinced that in $x = 0$ is differentiable. What I am still not convinced is that in your first reasoning, the only point with troubles is the zero, because the problem is not just having a zero in a term, the problem is that $sen(b_n\zeta_n)$ "cancel" the $a_nb_n$ and the the sum remains bounded.

Comment: Since $\xi_n$ is dependent on $h$, you can choose $\xi_n$ arbitrarily close to $x$. Hence, $\sin(b_n\xi_n)\approx\sin(b_nx)$ due to $\sin x$ being (uniformly) continuous. Thus, in order to cancel out *infinitely* many $a_nb_n$ terms, $x$ has to be a root of $\sin(b_mx)$ for infinitely many values of $m$. But this is not possible.

Comment: Well there is a problem, in the first equation when you use the identity of $cos A - cos B$ it doesnt yield $sen(h/2)$, it yields $sen(b_nh/2)$ that is a problem because now $\zeta$ depends on $h$ but also on $n$, that imply that you can not take the term out of the series in the last equation. :(

Comment: Answering to your last comment, I agree that $sin(b_n\zeta_n) \approx sin(b_nx)$ but what happens if $sin(b_nx) \to 0$ with $n\to \infty$. In such case $sin(b_n\zeta_n) \to 0$ ... a problem

Comment: I think I found a nicer and less troublesome solution. Give me 5'.

Comment: No, it didn't work. I'll mark my answer as a large comment.